# Creating an instance of an activity in other activity and get its view

Tags: android

I have two activities. In the first one, I want to instantize the second activity and get its view. Is it possible to do so? Any help will be appreciated.

I am using Feinstein Sliding drawer: https://github.com/sockeqwe/SlidingMenu
I am passing two layouts in setContentView and setSecondaryView. But the problem is how to handle the events on those views?

Comment: very wrong do not create an instance of an activity class. activity has its own lifecycle. you declare it in manifest and it is started by `startActivity(intent)`

Comment: This isn't possible, but I don't see that any situation would require you to do this. Care to explain a bit more about the situation? It could be achieved by passing the View trough through the intents though.

Comment: Doesn't this allow you to atleast access the contentView?

Comment: @TimKranen It does, but I want to handle it in different class. Here I have to handle all the events for both drawers in same class.

Comment: Are you able to subclass the Activity? If so you can access the views without having to handle them all in one class.

Comment: I created a class with a constructor, in which i passed both context of main activity and view of my drawer. There I can handle the events :D